# How to center column and row item in Flutter?

Tags: grid, flutter-layout

I have a small currency table. I didn't use grid. I used Column and rows. Problem is that items in rows is not showing in center as shown below in the Excel example.
What widget do I have to use to make the items centered?

[image]

The Example codes:

```
return new Center(
  child: new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
            child: new Icon(
              Icons.crop_rotate,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
            child: new Text("STG", style: mainHeadTextStyle),
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
            child: new Text("EUR", style: mainHeadTextStyle),
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
            child: new Text("USD", style: mainHeadTextStyle),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 238, accepted):

If you want the whole table to be `Centered`, use the **`mainAxisAlignment`** property of **`Column`**.

**Column**

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center //Center Column contents vertically,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center //Center Column contents horizontally,
```

**Row**

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center //Center Row contents horizontally,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center //Center Row contents vertically,
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use `Spacer` if you want fine grain control.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Spacer(), // 1st spacer
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
    Spacer(), // 2nd spacer
  ],
)
```

---

You can change `flex` too using `Spacer(flex:2)`

Answer (score 15):

If you want it to be like in the picture, use

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly
```