# how do i center widgets inside row?

Tags: android, flutter

So I have this code I tried using center() widget but I can't get the element in the center here's how they look.
[image: here's the snip]

the funny thing is the green container consumes all the screen width but the widgets inside the container are not aligned to center horizontally.

here's the code

```dart
    Center(
        child: Container(
          color : Colors.green,
          alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
            child:  Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                        child: Text(
                            " Likes \n" + document['likes'].toString()),
                        onTap: () => LikeQuote(document),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                        child: Text(" Dislikes \n" +
                            document['dislikes'].toString()),
                        onTap: () => DislikeQuote(document),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                        child: Text(" Shares \n" +
                            document['shares'].toString()),
                        onTap: () => ShareQuote(),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I want the like dislike and share to be in the center . How do i do that?

Comment: In your Row, try mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to centred column and row item in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871033/how-to-centred-column-and-row-item-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the widget within a Row or Columns, we can use these parameters inside Row or Columns.

```
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,              
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

Row:

- mainAxisAlignment determine horizontally align the path
- crossAxisAlignment determine vertically align the path

Column:

- mainAxisAlignment determine vertically align the path
- crossAxisAlignment determine horizontally align the path

Comment: ok that works fine what if i want it like dislike and share widgets to get a width of 33% of the screen width each.

Comment: to use percent in height and width, you can use of FractionallySizedBox widget. if you want to fill empty places in Row or Column, you can use of Expanded widget for them children. @TauseefAhmad

Answer (score 2):

You should use `mainAxisAlignment`

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children:[ comp1(), comp2()
```

Comment: where should i use this?

Comment: as a property of the Row constructor, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
          color : Colors.green,
          alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),

          child:  Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                child: Text(
                    " Likes \n" + document['likes'].toString()),
                onTap: () => LikeQuote(document),
              ),
              InkWell(
                child: Text(" Dislikes \n" +
                    document['dislikes'].toString()),
                onTap: () => DislikeQuote(document),
              ),
              InkWell(
                child: Text(" Shares \n" +
                    document['shares'].toString()),
                onTap: () => ShareQuote(),
              ),
            ],
          )
          ,
        ),
```